# How do I filter a list with date and time values by only extracting specific times each day?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have a list of days and times in column A. Column B is a dollar value for each time value.

[image]

[image]

I want to get a specific time for each day and list the price in the next column. I have this right now:

[image]

The formula for column J is this:

```
=filter(A11:B,(mod(A11:A,1)*24)>=4.5,(mod(A11:A,1)*24)<=4.6)
```

This formula filters 4:30AM and the price associated with it.

Formula for column L is this:

```
=filter(A11:B,(mod(A11:A,1)*24)>=9.5,(mod(A11:A,1)*24)<=9.6)
```

Which filters only 9:30AM for each day and the price that goes with it.

As you can see, the dates stop matching when column J is 8/12/2021 and column L is 8/13/2021. This is because column L didn't have 9:30AM for 8/12/2021 so it skipped to 8/13/2021.

How can I make so that one of the columns skip a date if the other column doesn't match that time? I don't know if I explained that well but in the example above, column J should skip 8/12/2021 because column L didn't have 8/12/2021.

Another way of dealing with this issue is perhaps using UNIQUE and FILTER formulas but I'm not sure how that could be done. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's a link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TvP0_UsYJbLb5bscx2e4nTEnSkP5roBZpP8aIGdl414/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TvP0_UsYJbLb5bscx2e4nTEnSkP5roBZpP8aIGdl414/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but if you need to filter values so the time element is 09:30 and 04:30, then hide values where a date only occurs once (ie. no 09:30 value or no 04:30 value), you could use:

```
=arrayformula(filter(
filter(A11:B,(round(mod(A11:A,1)*24,2)=9.5)+(round(mod(A11:A,1)*24,2)=4.5)),
countif(int(filter(A11:A,(round(mod(A11:A,1)*24,2)=9.5)+(round(mod(A11:A,1)*24,2)=4.5))),int(filter(A11:A,(round(mod(A11:A,1)*24,2)=9.5)+(round(mod(A11:A,1)*24,2)=4.5))))>1)
)
```

Adjust `>1` at the end to whatever logic you need (`=2`, `<>1` etc).

You can also add `sort()` around everything if you need to.

**Explanation:**

It turns out that `mod(A11,1)*24` doesn't round particularly well, so I suggest `round(mod(A11:A,1)*24,2)`.

Therefore to filter the date/times for 9.30am and 4.30am, you can apply:

`round(mod(A11:A,1)*24,2)=9.5`

and

`round(mod(A11:A,1)*24,2)=4.5`

like this:

```
=arrayformula({filter(A11:B,(round(mod(A11:A,1)*24,2)=9.5)+(round(mod(A11:A,1)*24,2)=4.5))})
```

`filter` is usually `AND` but to get `OR` condition it's `filter(A:B,(A=1)+(A=2))`

This gets the dates only:

```
=arrayformula(int(filter(A11:A,(round(mod(A11:A,1)*24,2)=9.5)+(round(mod(A11:A,1)*24,2)=4.5))))
```

Then this counts how many times a date appears:

```
=arrayformula(countif(int(filter(A11:A,(round(mod(A11:A,1)*24,2)=9.5)+(round(mod(A11:A,1)*24,2)=4.5))),int(filter(A11:A,(round(mod(A11:A,1)*24,2)=9.5)+(round(mod(A11:A,1)*24,2)=4.5)))))
```

Combining the elements gets the solution.

I'll add a tab to your sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter each list on finding a match for each date (integer part of datetime) in the other list:

In J:

```
=filter(A11:B,(mod(A11:A,1)*24)>=4.5,(mod(A11:A,1)*24)<=4.6,isnumber(match(int(A11:A),int(filter(A11:A,(mod(A11:A,1)*24)>=9.5,(mod(A11:A,1)*24)<=9.6)),0)))
```

In L:

```
=filter(A11:B,(mod(A11:A,1)*24)>=9.5,(mod(A11:A,1)*24)<=9.6,isnumber(match(int(A11:A),int(filter(A11:A,(mod(A11:A,1)*24)>=4.5,(mod(A11:A,1)*24)<=4.6)),0)))
```

*Note*

Plz see Aresvik's answer for a possibly better approach to rounding, but note that 4:30 (3/16) actually has an exact representation as a binary decimal so rounding errors aren't an issue here.

Comment: Awesome I think this one worked. What I was looking for was in column G because it skips 8/13/2021 since it doesn't contain a 4:30AM time. Thanks so much!